# Bigquery: Append to a nested record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm currently checking out Bigquery, and I want to know if it's possible to add new data to a nested table.

For example, if I have a table like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "name": "phone",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "number",
                "type": "STRING"
            },
            {
                "name": "type",
                "type": "STRING"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And then I insert a phone number for the contact John Doe.

```
INSERT into socialdata.phones_examples (name, phone) VALUES("Jonh Doe", [("555555", "Home")]);
```

Is there an option to later add another number to the contact ? To get something like this:

[image: Append example]

I know I can update the whole field, but I want to know if there is way to append to the nested table new values.

Comment: Is this a record or JSON?  Are you trying to modify in place or just add in the result set?

Comment: A record. I've added more info and an example output. In other words, I want to know if I treat the record field as another table, where I can append more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you insert data into BigQuery, the granularity is the level of rows, not elements of the arrays contained within rows. You would want to use a query like this, where you update the relevant row and append to the array:

```
UPDATE socialdata.phones_examples
SET phone = ARRAY_CONCAT(phone, [("555555", "Home")])
WHERE name = "Jonh Doe"
```

Answer (score 4):

if you need to update multiple records for some users - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `socialdata.phones_examples` t
SET phone = ARRAY_CONCAT(phone, [new_phone]) 
FROM (
  SELECT 'John Doe' name, STRUCT<number STRING, type STRING>('123-456-7892', 'work') new_phone UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Abc Xyz' , STRUCT('123-456-7893', 'work') new_phone 
) u
WHERE t.name = u.name
```

or if those updates are available in some table (for example `socialdata.phones_updates`):

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `socialdata.phones_examples` t
SET phone = ARRAY_CONCAT(phone, [new_phone]) 
FROM `socialdata.phones_updates` u
WHERE t.name = u.name
```

Comment: This is not a commentary on this solution, but I was wondering if this would fall under the table quota & limits of “Daily destination table update limit — 1,000 updates per table per day”.

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking for as it is solely depends on how many times you run it  - right?

Comment: So, your saying that the above query can be run at most 1000 times a day?

Comment: just read respective documentation or post specific question. i doubt above answer anyhow will affect those limits